# WordPress plugin icon does not show up

Tags: wordpress-plugin-creation

I followed this tutorial: http://darrinb.com/adding-custom-icon-wordpress-plugin/

I added the assets/icon-128-128.jpg

But icon does not show up after release to plugin store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried renaming the file to `icon-128x128.png` ?
this is a known problem in the wordpress community.

here is another way to solve your problem

- Inserting this:

```css
---theme
    fonts
      fontawesome-webfont.eot
      ...
    css
      fontawesome.css
      ...
```